# How do I single sign on between Bugzilla and Node.js?

Tags: apache, node.js, single-sign-on, mod-perl2

Bugzilla runs behind the Apache webserver (mod_perl2) and stores the users in MySQL database. Node.js is it's own webserver. How do I single sign on the user in the Node.js app using the user data which present in Bugzilla's MySQL database?

Update: As Ravi has mentioned in comments below, I am not looking for a solution to authenticate users. I am looking for a solution that allows users that have already been authenticated in Bugzilla to be able to login to a Node.js app without being re-prompted for an authentication. In other words, I am looking for a Single Sign On.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812979/how-to-make-authentication-in-node-js-that-i-can-use-for-my-website

Comment: @John my head hurt trying to understand that question. Both grammar and logic were atrocious. I ended up spending an hour just to edit that question till it made sense. What I discovered in the end was that it was about authentication, not SSO. Don't do that to me again. If you want to punish me, just tell me to do fifty push ups instead :-)

Comment: @RHT, just so it's clear to me: you want not so much to authenticate in the Node app against the user data in the Bugzilla MySQL DB, but you actually want a logged in Bugzilla user to be recognised as authenticated on the Node app as well? (this sort of implies to me that the Node app needs access to the Bugzilla login cookie and use it for its own verification).

Comment: There should be central session that should be shared between two or more apps. If someone comes to Node.js app and if the session for that particular user is set then the app should redirect him/her to Members area else should ask for prompt. This applies to BugZilla also. This is the problem which I am also trying to solve currently. There is a plugin [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Addons) for bugzilla. Give it a try.

Comment: I can see that there are a couple of nodejs modules that do single sign on. I will give them a try if I get some time. You gotta love the nodejs community. https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/sso

Comment: The solution may involve installing a separate LDAP server that both Bugzilla and nodejs can point to.